# What should be done about competing duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion

So I take time to put in a well thought-out explanation with a link to a blog that I found on the subject that would solve the problem at hand. Someone else posts a day later with the same answer, in his own words, with essentially link to a blog with a repost of the blog link I provided.

What can I do about this? We would all like our credit where credit is due. Would it be in the best judgement of SharePoint StackExchange to keep both answers? I feel this can go either way. Maybe he explained it better or maybe he is going off my answer and building on it?

Ideas?

Comment: Good question Mike, I think if it happened just once, you can ignore it, but if it keeps happening and person keeps copying content of your answer then it should be questionable. If the other person really want to contribute then why not improve the answer which is already there or just add a comment on it instead of copying part of answer already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to keep both answers. Usually one answer is clearly better and will attract the upvotes or the "accepted answer" check mark.

In the event that both answers are very similar, you should consider improving your answer. Otherwise, I typically award the upvotes to the person who posted the answer first.

Comment: I agree with @Kit, as I've seen posts where a user had posted just a link to a site. However, another person may have linked to the same site, but posted the relevant materials that answered the question. In sucha case, why would the original poster receive the points?

Comment: this is also a good point as well. The biggest reason this would be important is in the event that a link gets broken, the answer that has summarized the link still offers good information whereas the link gives you nothing at all